# Passing data from table row to PartialView

Tags: model-view-controller

How can I pass all my data to PartialView.

My table code look like this.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.listContract)
    {
        <tr style="font-size:11px;">
            <td>View more info</td>
            <td>@item.ID</td>
            <td>@item.name</td>
            <td>@item.Phone</td>
            <td>@item.Passport</td>
            <td>@item.CustomerID</td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Controller bind data to ViewModel pass to View

```
public ActionResult MethodName(){
    var viewmodel = new ViewModel();
    //bind data to ViewModel
    return View(viewmodel)
}
```

In View pass partial view data as list model

View :

```
@model ViewModel

@Html.Partial("PartialViewName", Model.DataList)
```

Partial View :

```
@model List<Model>

@foreach(var item in Model){
 .....
}
```

ViewModel :

```
 public class ViewModel {
    //properties for View
    ....

    //property for partial view
    public List<Model> DataList {get; set;}

 }
```